# How do I control the ranges in plots made with LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

[image: LogLogPlot Graph]

I have two graphs (Out[45] and Out[47]), both made with `LogLogPlot`.

For some reason, I can't see the lower part in those graphs, the third graph (Out[51]) shows both functions on same graph, but again cant see the lower parts of both functions

I use the option `PlotRange` to try to change the vertical range on the plots, but it didnt work, maybe because of `LogLogPlot`.

Please, any helpfull hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `PlotRange -> All`.

Answer (score 1):

Changed answer (thanks to Bob Hanlon)

You need to specify `PlotRange->All`. Also increase `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`.

```
fen[y_] := (3.44479 + 3.29645 Sin[y])^0.5

LogLogPlot[fen[y], {y, 0.001, 100},
 PlotStyle -> Black,
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 60,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 MaxRecursion -> 10]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much - I changed the answer

Answer (score 0):

I look first the fen function and ploted it, look that values range over the 0 so in this part do not have problem to be loglogploted but in this loglogplot i forced the axes to be origin in 0.05 and 0.25 to have the graph in good sigth

```
 fen[y_] := (3.44479 + 3.296645*Sin[y])^(1/2)



 Plot[fen[y], {y, 0.001, 100}]
```

then

```
LogLogPlot[fen[y], {y, 0.01, 100}, AxesOrigin -> {0.05, 0.25}]
```

sorry I can not paste plots here I do not know how to do